# Does anyone know why the SimpleFTPSample that apple provides leaks memory?

Tags: ftp, ios, memory-leak-detector

I noticed that the SimpleFTPSample that apple provides leaks memory.  The Leaks Performance tool detects a leak when using the "List" sample.  A leak is detected after you press the "List" button the second time.  Does anyone know why?  ie have a fix?  I am considering using FTP in my app, but don't want to create a leaky app.  Thanks.

Comment: Post the code?  Point out where it leaks?

Comment: link to code sample: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(oh old Question)**
In the Statusbar under Build use "Build and Analyse" this points out a leak in line 85 of `AppDelegate.m`  `Potential leak of object allocated on line 85 and stored into initialDefaultsChanged`
My solution is to release initialsDefaults after register it to Defaults on line 96

```
#if ! TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *   initialDefaultsChanged;

        initialDefaultsChanged = [initialDefaults mutableCopy];
        assert(initialDefaultsChanged != nil);

        [initialDefaultsChanged setObject:@"" forKey:@"CreateDirURLText"];
        [initialDefaultsChanged setObject:@"" forKey:@"PutURLText"];

        initialDefaults = initialDefaultsChanged;
    }
    #endif

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:initialDefaults];
    [initialDefaults release];//add this
```